# QGIS highlighted cell issues

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon

Does anyone know why this is occurring? I obviously want the yellow highlighted polygon boundary to be always on top. Currently, the non selected shared boundaries are rendering on top of the highlighted polygon.

I created these polygons using the split feature, so which ever polygon was split first appears to have priority. I have checked geometries, they are all valid with no overlaps or gaps.

[image: Yellow highlight line should follow vertices, but is overwritten by some shared boundaries.]

I can work around this by using simple fill, which will highlight the whole polygon as yellow or I can offset the simple line so it does not interfere with the highlighted line. Both solutions are not ideal for my workflow.